# Validate select2 field before processing my form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-select2

I'm trying to validate a small form in which I have 3 fields and one of them I load a select field using php, all this works fine, now when trying to use select2 for this field, jquery-validate does not seem to take it into account, and Searched for solution, but not found one that suits my validation rules in my code js, how could I solve this?.

I have reviewed several questions related to this in OS, trying to adapt it to my code but it does not work for me. I need an idea how to solve this

```html
<form id="form-reservation" action="<?php echo base_url();?>reservation/save" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label">customer</label>
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="select2" id="cus" name="cus">
        <option>Select customer</option>
        <?php
          foreach ($get as $id => $name)
            echo '<option  value="',$id,'">'.$name.'</option>';
        ?> 
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label">Monthly amount</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="monthly" name="monthly" placeholder="0.00">
      <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label">total amount</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="total" name="total" placeholder="0.00">
      <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-squared btn-info margin-inline">submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

my js

```js
$('document').ready(function(){
  $(".select2").select2();

  $('#form-reservation').validate({
      rules: {
        cus:{
          required: true
        },
        monthly:{
          number: true,
          required: true
        },
        total:{
          number: true,
          required: true
        }
      },
      highlight: function (input) {
        $(input).parents('.form-group').addClass('has-danger');
      },
      unhighlight: function (input) {
        $(input).parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-danger');
      },
      errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        $(element).parents('.form-group').append(error);
      },
      submitHandler : function(_form){
        $.ajax({
          url: form.attr('action'),
          type: form.attr('method'),
          data: form.serialize(),
          dataType: 'json',
          success:function(response){
          }
        })
       return false;
      }
  });});
```

Comment: i don't know about your problem, but it seem your php code has bad syntax: **echo '<option  value="',$id,'">'.$name.'</option>';** must be **echo '<option  value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';**

Comment: My problem is that I can not validate my select2 field

Answer (score -1):

Yes... it's a promblem in you code, change

```
value="',$id,'" to 
value="'.$id.'"
```

Comment: My problem is that I can not validate my select2 field